# Reverse Engineering JBoss Application

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x

Is there a way to reverse engineer a Jboss web application with only the build of the application?

Regards,
Brat

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this without sounding malicious?

Comment: You can do it in one click but first tell us why.

Comment: @Bernard Well I am not sounding Malicious... I need to learn to perform my job in a better way.

Comment: @stas : I dont know JBoss too much. I have my own sample application. To which I was thinking to do reverse engineer so that when in my job I am asked to do it.. I could do it without searching the whole web and without wasting my time(and not understanding a thing about it).

Comment: @Brat Rosm: And what job would that be? You need to be more forthcoming about your intentions.

Comment: Well If u think I am sounding you people wrong here so please dont tell me... My intentions are clear. We dont have the code for our upcoming project and at this point of time we only have the build. Just planning things out. If that sounds malicious to you. Then you dont have to reply about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A web application is basically a .war file containing all the stuff, which is a renamed zip archive and you can extract it using your favourite unzipping program.
Once decompressed, you will find:

- Web pages (commonly JSPs): there's no need to reverse anything.
- Config files: again, they are just fine
- class files: this is the tricky part, since you have to decompile them. there is a lot of software to do that ([this](http://dj.navexpress.com/), for instance)
- JARs: they are libraries, most likely third party libraries so, again, nothing to do. Maybe some of them are not third party libraries, and you have to decompress them (yes, renamed zip files) and you will find .class files inside.

It's pretty hard to be exhaustive, just wanted to point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks... But can you please provide me a different link of a software which is opensource....

Comment: [Pick](http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=java+decompiler) your favourite.

Comment: .war? lol. I think you mean .jar?

Comment: @stas, no he means .war (web application repository or something close to that)

Comment: oh. never heard of it :P

Comment: well -6 vote's !!! Wow what a _________!!!